# passing function as prop, undefined error

Tags: reactjs

I m trying to pass a prop to my child component.

```
onChangeNumber: e => {
  console.log(e);
};

class MyDrinking extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Flexible>
        <LYDSlider
          {...sceneConfig}
          onChangeNumber={this.onChangeNumber.bind(this)}
          value={sceneConfig.sliderNumberValue}
        />
      </Flexible>
    );
  }
}
```

Keep getting this.props.onChangeNumber is not a function.

Any ideas?

Comment: change your onchange method  to `onChangeNumber(e) {
  console.log(e); 
};`

Comment: Thanks, still get is not a function error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the function is not defined as a property inside of your class.

```
class MyDrinking extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onChangeNumber = this.onChangeNumber.bind(this);
    }
    onChangeNumber(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Flexible>
              <LYDSlider
                {...sceneConfig}
                onChangeNumber={this.onChangeNumber}
                value={sceneConfig.sliderNumberValue}
              />
            </Flexible>
        );
    }
}
```